# NodeJS module resolution summary

Tags: node.js, module

All the documents that I read talks about the order of where Node.js will be *looking* for dependent modules, however, none of them talk about its order of *picking* them (the module resolution). I.e.,

Does Node.js pick the *first* module from the searched/found list, or the *last*? What if there are different versions of same module found?

Also, where can I find a summary of where Node.js will be looking for dependent modules, i.e. the *full* list of its searching orders? Even 
https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together is not listing them all in once place. Thx

PS,

answering *"One might ask why you would have duplicate named modules in the places that it searches any way? That seems like a recipe for confusion anyway"*... take a look at this:

```
$ du -csm * 
1       config.json
1       handler.js
1       launch.sh
1       LICENSE
1       mailgun.js
1       main.js
352     node_modules
1       package.json
1       package-lock.json
1       README.md
1       reloader.js
1       support.js
1       test
352     total

$ mv node_modules .. 

$ du -csk * 
4       config.json
4       handler.js
4       launch.sh
4       LICENSE
4       mailgun.js
4       main.js
4       package.json
100     package-lock.json
4       README.md
4       reloader.js
8       support.js
28      test
184     total
```

So the answer is, as Aluan Haddad put it, *"most do not seem to care and the answer matters"*. I.e., let me spell it out for you:

- Without the `node_modules` folder, my own files is less than 200K, and within that 200K, `package-lock.json` *alone* is 100K. I.e., even without `node_modules` the overhead is already **120%**.
- With the `node_modules` folder, the overhead will be a whopping **176000%**, calculating on the 200K code bases, if using 100K, then that percentage need to be **doubled**.

*"most do not seem to care"*, sigh. *Why do I care?* because I'll be writing a bunch of similar projects based on the same node modules, and I'm not going to throw that `176000%` overheads all over the places. I know most people would not be facing such extreme cases, but *why would you care?* If you ever need to write more than one `express` projects, then you should care.

The answer to this question is the base to the answer, *what if different projects need to base on different versions of `express`* (e.g., express4.x and express3.x etc). Of course, someone just *don't care*.

PPS,

I was reading an [interesting article](https://medium.com/@sAbakumoff/github-cancer-180db780d99d) the other day, which is before I'm getting into the JS/NodeJS business, and I'd encourage every NodeJS developer to read it, and think about the deep reason(s) behind the [*"GitHub Cancer"*](https://medium.com/@sAbakumoff/github-cancer-180db780d99d) phenomenon.

PPPS,

Was reading yet another interesting article that I cannot resist sharing it back here --

[What’s really wrong with node_modules and why this is your fault](https://hackernoon.com/whats-really-wrong-with-node-modules-and-why-this-is-your-fault-8ac9fa893823)

[image]

Comment: TL;DR; it picks the first one. More people should ask this question however, as while the answer is not hard to find, most do not seem to care and the answer matters.

Comment: One might ask why you would have duplicate named modules in the places that it searches any way?  That seems like a recipe for confusion anyway.

Comment: Not sure to understand if your question is about node.js or npm. For node.js, it's pretty simple: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules

Comment: @RaphaMex, I'm talking about https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders, or alike, i.e., about _both_ node.js _and_ npm.